# How can add Tab widget to the botton in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android, i want to add tab widget to the bottom of page. this is the code of my xml file:-

```
    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fillViewport="true" android:scrollbars="none">
       <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
 </HorizontalScrollView>  
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

by this code the tabwidget is adding to the top of the layout as shown in below picture:-
[image]
please tell what should i so to add these "**Albums**" tabWidget ?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the correct way to do this.**

```
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="5dp">

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ScrollView01"/>

    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fillViewport="true" android:scrollbars="none" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

       <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
   </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is code for bottom tab,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just paste this on your main.xml